# Boost C++ VS 2010 _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I am using the following command to build the Boost libraries:

C:\Code\Libraries\boost_1_51_0>bjam toolset=msvc-10.0 variant=debug,release threading=multi link=static define="**_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0**"

But the debug libraries still show _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 in the dumpbin tool (output of dumpbin tool is shown below). How can I build a debug version of Boost libs with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0?

**Output of the dumpbin tool:**

Dump of file C:\code\Libraries\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

Linker Directives

/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1600"

/FAILIFMISMATCH:**"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2"**

/DEFAULTLIB:"msvcprtd"

/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib"

/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib"

/DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRTD"

/DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"

Comment: Does the following syntax work: `define=_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`?